# Percent change in abundance per genus and treatment

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I am new to using tydir but I really like its simplicity. However, I am stuck trying to figure out how to calculate the percent change in abundance per treatment of each specific Genus. For example how much the genus Pyronemal increased in abundance after the fire.

My data contains three columns: Abundance of each taxa in questions, treatment (burned vs unburned) and Genus (Pyronema, Basidioascus, etc), in total I have 15 Genus(15 Genus, 2 treatments (burned vs unburned), and their respective abundances).

```
SampleID | Treatment| Abundance | Genus           
   CNF1T1  |  Burned  |   0.23    | Pyronema  
   CNF2T1  |  Burned  |   0.10    | Aspergillus

   CNF3T1  |  Unburned|   0.02    | Pyronema  
   CNF4T1  |  Unburned|   0.05    | Aspergillus
```

Snapshot of my metadata :

[image]

After looking through the site, I have seen a few codes I could use but it does not seem to be going what I need it to do. **See below:** The code I used does not seem to group the percents by Treatment or Genus. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, but if someone could please help I would really appreciate it:

The code I have used is as follows, with slight variations of the same code, based on what I have found on this site.

Code used:

```
    `Gen15MeltTrt %>% 
    group_by(Treatment, Genus) %>% 
    transmute(percent = 100 * Abundance / sum(Abundance))`***
```

I used `transmute` since I wanted to create a new table containing only the variables of interest.

Output from code above

```
> Treatment  |     Genus     | Percent**
> 
>  Unburned    |  Inocybe      | 10.1 
> 
>  Unburned    | Coniothyrium  | 21.0 
> 
>  Unburned    | Cladophialophora | 4.65
> 
>  Unburned    | Cladophialophora | 4.65
> 
>  Unburned    | Cladophialophora | 4.65
> 
>  Burned      |   Pyronema       | 1.48
> 
>  Unburned    |   Pyronema       | 30.5 
> 
>  Burned      |   Pyronema       | 1.48
> 
>  Burned      |  Penicillium     | 1.82
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow and R and dplyr! One tip for asking questions: Its way easier if you try to distill the problem you are facing and preferably put it into a context that is easy for anyone to understand. An easy way to do this is to find the problem you are facing in a dataset that is available in R. Below I have tried to give you an answer based on the `ChickWeight` dataset. It includes a bunch of very handy functions in dplyr which i recommend you sink your teeth into: `group_by`,`mutate` and `first`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- ChickWeight

df %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>% 
  mutate(percent = (weight - first(weight))/first(weight)*100)
```

Edit: 
Get percentage change for each treatment (Type of Diet in the `ChickWeight` dataset.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Diet,Time) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(weight,na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(percent = (mean - first(mean))/first(mean)*100)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was trying my best to make a clear question, so thank you for your comment. I do have a followup question. When I calculate it with the formula you posted, it does calculate the percent but it calculates it per sample, I want to group the samples per treatment so that I get 1 value. When I do it by in base R as : Trt<-(((732-1629)/1629)*100);Trt#-----55.06446%

Comment: I want to make sure I know how to do it, since I will be doing a longer calculation with 10-time points, and I figured I can check my work by starting with just treatment.

Comment: Aha! I have edited my answer. I hope it helps. If this is not what you need then i encourage you to try to use some of the datasets included in R to specify your exact question. If it does answer your question the please mark it with the correct answer button :)